# What is a good obfuscator that is FIPS compliant?

Tags: .net, obfuscation, fips

We're getting ready to release an upgrade to an ISV product that is FIPS 140-2 compliant, and just found out that our current obfuscator isn't.

Can anyone point me towards a good .Net obfuscator that is FIPS 140-2 compliant and preferably doesn't break the bank?

Comment: What does it mean for a .NET obfuscator to be FIPS 140-2 compliant? What's your current one?

Comment: I scanned through the [FIPS 140-2 Standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402.pdf) and *I couldn't find anything relating to obfuscation.* It only relates to cryptology (with restrictions on where/how it can be run). Is there a larger context being omitted? (It seems like Security Level 1 is a "gimme" ;-)

Comment: Ahh, found something that might be relevant Level 1: "All cryptographic software and firmware shall be installed in a form *that protects the software and 
firmware source and executable code from unauthorized disclosure and modification.*" ... I wonder how that's "read". It seems to imply that this protection does not need to happen in the software itself, but I'm no lawyer and since google "FIPS 140 obfuscator" gets like 0 hits ...

Comment: In short, to be FIPS 140-2 compliant, you must use ONLY cryptographic module implementations that are FIPS 140-2 VALIDATED, which requires formal testing + limits them to only certain algorithms of certain strengths.  So in the .Net world, without resorting to 3rd party modules

Comment: So in the .Net world, you cannot use AesManaged, but can use AesCryptoServiceProvider, for example, since AesCryptoServiceProvider calls down a module that is FIPS-validated.  This is REQUIRED if you sell to the federal or most (all?) state governments.

Comment: The premise here is that many obfuscators perform some amount of encryption as part of the obfuscation process.

Comment: @Scott: Are you saying that your obfuscator produces code that does not run on a system configured for FIPS 140-2 compliance? Since the de-obfuscation process is not something I would consider a cryptographic function, it doesn't have to use only validated modules.

Comment: A system "configured for FIPS 140-2 compliance" is no more than changing a reg key that does nothing - it is up to each "non-compliant" crypto function to throw an exception if the key is set - not all 3rd party crypto libraries do this - so "does not run on" a system doesn't mean that it is FIPS compliant.  That being said, in our case I was told that it actually does throw an exception if the FIPS reg key is set.  Many obfuscators encrypt strings and then unwrap them at runtime - that is a crypto function.

Answer (score 4):

DISCLAIMER: We are developer of Babel Obfuscator

Also [Babel Obfuscator](http://www.babelfor.net/products) can produce FIPS compliant assemblies.

Comment: Excelent product, I'm not part of the Babel team but I've used it for years now (since free version to paid one). It provides wide configuration options, from commands, xml or GUI, definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: We are the developers of Crypto Obfuscator.

[Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) can produce FIPS compliant assemblies - it uses only FIPS approved encryption algorithms for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

There are .NET obfuscators that can be set to only modify the IL of the assembly itself and not bundle the binary in any sort of wrapper.  Provided you only use FIPS compliant crypto functions in your assembly, the output you get from them should also be FIPS compliant.

Those that I know of that should do this are:

- [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview%20Dotfuscator) (definitely will)
- [smartassembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/)
  (you may need to turn off resource
  encryption, also the XAML/BAML protection may use non-FIPS algorithms)
- [eazfuscator](http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx) (same caveats as above)
- [skater](http://www.rustemsoft.com/freeware_obfuscator.htm) (same caveats as above)
- [SharpObfuscator](http://sharpobfuscator.codeplex.com/)
- [obfuscar](http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/)

Comment: Dotfuscator: "Discovered Dotfuscator's tamper and analytics features are not FIPS compliant. There's 2 hours I won't see again!" -@GarrardKitchen
SmartAssembly: "I have a machine on which FIPS is enabled. When I try to build a project in SmartAssembly, it says "InvalidOperationException : The current implementation is not FIPS compliant" - http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?p=46971#46971
Quick search didn't turn up any discussion for the smaller ones

Comment: The comment above that I found regarding SmartAssembly brings up another issue - even if you don't use a feature that generates non-compliant binaries, some of them won't even be able to obfuscate on the dev machine if the FIPS reg key is set.

Comment: @ScottBai Dotfuscator should execute on a FIPS machine. It also does not add any non-FIPS code *unless* you use some extra features such as Tamper Detection or track application usage with Runtime Intelligence.  Obfuscation itself should not cause noncompliance.